# How to go to link with particular tab active?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here Is the link that I have tried

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url') . 'index.php/back-office-panel/User_master#tab4' ?>">
```

But its not working
suggest answers.

I want to go to edit of that particulate section which is tab format.

Comment: <a href= "<?php echo config->item('base_url).'index.php/back-office-pannel/User_master#tab4'?>"   This is the A tag i have given

Comment: If it's like a bootstrap tab, you need to write a little js to handle flipping to the tab based upon the `#hash`

Comment: yes it is a bootstrap tab....which consist of forms for updating user details @hash- Lawrence Cherone

Answer (score 2):

Simple pass the `uri` `parameter`  `'index.php/back-office-panel/User_master/tab4'`

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url') . 'index.php/back-office-panel/User_master/tab4' ?>">
```

**PHP:** Check the `condition` and echo the `active` `class` in `tab.`

```
if(isset($this->uri->segment(3)) && $this->uri->segment(3)=='tab4'){

    echo 'active'; 

}
```

Comment: <select>   <option>

Comment: <select>   <option <?php if($key['state_id']==$State->id){echo "active"}else {echo "";} ?>           </select>                                                                                                               
                                                                                              I have tried this type of code but still its not working ....and as you told is same kind of so ....if any other solution please suggest ............by using jquery of js